# How to add a list of lists as one row to dataframe, with each list in one cell? - Python

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a lists of lists, that I want to convert to one row in a DataFrame. Each list should come in a cell in the DataFrame. When completed, I want to add the next list of lists in the same way.

This is what I do:

```
import pandas as pd
lst1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]    
lst2 = [['j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['p', 'q', 'r']]    
DataFrame = []
df = pd.DataFrame(lst1)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst2)
```

Resulting in:

```
          0     1    2
0         j     k    l
1         m     n    o
2         p     q    r
```

But what I would like is this:

```
         0                1                2
0        ['a', 'b', 'c']  ['d', 'e', 'f']  ['g', 'h', 'i']
1        ['j', 'k', 'l']  ['m', 'n', 'o']  ['p', 'q', 'r']
```

Is there a simpler and elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is this what you need ?

```
pd.DataFrame([lst1,lst2])
Out[500]: 
           0          1          2
0  [a, b, c]  [d, e, f]  [g, h, i]
1  [j, k, l]  [m, n, o]  [p, q, r]
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like.

Comment: Man, you are too fast!

Comment: @Vaishali haha , just time to break , so looking around the site . :-)

Comment: Can lst1, lst2 etc, also be added in a loop? So that it becomes possible to do the same for 100k lists of lists?

Comment: @twhale, this is a different question. But my advice is combine first into a list of lists, then combine into one dataframe at the end. Appending to a list is *much* cheaper than appending to a dataframe.

Comment: @twhale sorry what you mean done by loop? You need create those list firstly right?

Comment: I mean, I have a script that generates these lists of lists and there could be thousands. So I would like to add each new lst3, lst4, etc. as they are generated to the dataframe as well.

Comment: @twhale then you can add like this l=[], l.append(thelistyoucreated), then pd.DataFrame(l)

Comment: @jjp, sorry you are right this is a different question. Might be able to fix it based on your suggestion though. thanks